# Can anyone help me to get picture of sender in conversations with Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can anyone help me to get picture of sender in conversations with graph API?

I have have tried:

```
me/conversations?fields=id,senders{id,name,picture}
```

but I have get the error:

```
(#100) Invalid edge (senders) on node type (UnifiedThread)
```

Comment: is there a way to get sender photo in current graph api(v2.10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the api has been deprecated since 2.4 and thus you can't do that now. The `senders` field is an invalid edge as the message clearly states. 
[READ THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/inbox)  for more information

Comment: link READ THIS has been died